# Show multiple Columns contents in a ComboBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to show FirstName and LastName in a Combobox drop down.
The Problem is That I should work On 2 fields existing in a Table.
I checked the TDBlLookUpComboBox but the ListFields properties doesn't work for me in Delphi Xe.

I set The properties of TDBlLookUpComboBox to

```
DataSource :my datasource
ListFields : SUR_NAME;  FIRST_NAME
```

Now, I am doing it by a basic way :

```
nameClient := Concat( sqlqry1.Fields.FieldByName('FIRST_NAME').AsString,' ',
                      sqlqry1.Fields.FieldByName('SUR_NAME').AsString);
cbbClient.Items.Add(nameClient);
```

Comment: You should do this in your Select. It is way easier

Answer (score 4):

**Change the input**
Just change the source data going into the DBCombo by putting in a query:

```
select concat(SUR_NAME,' ',FIRST_NAME) as NAME, * from mytable;
```

Now you can display the data in your combo box.

**Make the output look nice in the combobox**
<sub>Obviously you'll be using a `TDBILookUpComboBox` but everything else is the same.</sub>

In order to make multiple columns in the drop down you'll have to do your own drawing.

This can be done by changing the `style` to `csOwnerDrawFixed` and assigning the `OnDrawItem` event.

See the sample code below:

```
unit Unit18;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm18 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form18: TForm18;

implementation

uses
  System.Types,
  StrUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm18.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  Columns: TStringDynArray;
  ColCount: Integer;
  ItemText: string;
  DC: HDC;
  DrawRect: TRect;
  Middle: integer;
begin
  ItemText:= ComboBox1.Items[index];
  Columns:= SplitString(ItemText, '|');
  ColCount:= Length(Columns);

  // For Demo purposes only the first 2 columns are displayed.
  DC:= ComboBox1.Canvas.Handle;
  Combobox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  Middle:= Rect.Left + Rect.Width div 2;
  Combobox1.Canvas.MoveTo(Middle, Rect.Top);
  Combobox1.Canvas.LineTo(Middle, Rect.Bottom);
  if ColCount > 0 then begin
    DrawRect:= Rect;
    OffsetRect(DrawRect,1,0);
    DrawRect.Right:= DrawRect.Right - DrawRect.Width div 2;
    DrawText(DC, Columns[0], Length(Columns[0]), DrawRect, 0);
  end;
  if ColCount > 1 then begin
    DrawRect:= Rect;
    OffsetRect(DrawRect,1,0);
    DrawRect.Left:= DrawRect.Left + DrawRect.Width div 2;
    DrawText(DC, Columns[1], Length(Columns[1]), DrawRect, 0);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Put the following text in the `Items`:

> test | test
>   line2 | part2
>   line 4 | part3
>   line 6

And this is what will be displayed:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me the TDBLookupComboBox is far the easiest solution - also when not associated to external data sets.

Creating a ClientDataSet, fields are defined via FieldDefs, and subsequently data may be added by code.

```
ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
ClientDataSet1.Open;
with ClientDataSet do
  begin
    Append;
    Fields[0].AsString := {string};
    Fields[1].AsString := {string};
    //etc.
    Post;
    Append;
    Fields[0].AsString := {string};
    Fields[1].AsString := {string};
    //etc.
    Post;
    //etc.
  end;
```

Hence the DBLookupComboBox’s properties ListSource, ListField (may include list of fields “field1;field2;field3”) and KeyField are defined corresponding the ClientDataSet, and properties DataSource and DataField may be left blank.
Hence you have your multi column combo box.
Retrieving selected items may be drawn as:

```
Procedure DBLookupComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
zStringOut := DBLookupComboBox1.ListSource.DataSet.Fields[n].AsString;
```

where zStringOut may be passed to some other procedure as desired.

Before distributing, remember including:

```
interface

uses
  MidasLib;
```

Best Regards